# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

i want to learn react.js and i try to do a simple android_application.
I want to create some "route" but i dont know why i can't compile and i don't understand the error.

```
tarting project at /home/guigui/loisirs/appp/Movies
Developer tools running on http://localhost:19002
Opening developer tools in the browser...
Unexpected token =
/home/guigui/loisirs/appp/Movies/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js:39
  _revisionsById = new Map();
                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/guigui/loisirs/appp/Movies/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:12:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at importMetroFromProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/src/MetroDevServer.ts:159:10)
    at Object.runMetroDevServerAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/src/MetroDevServer.ts:43:17)
    at Object.startDevServerAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/start/startDevServerAsync.ts:48:55)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

I searched on internet and tried "npm install", "npm install -S react-router-dom" but that doesn't function.

There is my app.js who is really simple.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

//components
import Test from '../components/Test';
import Home from 'components/Home';



//Run
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route exact path='/test' component={Test} />
         
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

*Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is this a react-native application?

Comment: Classical components structure for route is Router -> Switch -> Routes[], but here I see no Switch and not sure that any component except Route is allowed inside Switch. Try placing your div wrapper outside Router and provide Switch for Routes.

Comment: yes it's a react native application

Comment: ok thanks, i'm looking that

Comment: oh shit, i didn't know there are react js and react native! I did  a mix between my tutorials! Sorry and thanks for your help (never did js on my life)